# Swift - Cannot convert value of type 'Any?' to expected argument type 'String'

Tags: swift

```
if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] {
    
    if let nickn = json["nickname"] as? String {
        if(nickname != nickn){
            nickname = nickn
        }
    }
    
    var serverScalingString = ""
    serverScalingString += "0," + json["srvFile0"] as? String + "|"
    
    serverScaling = serverScalingString
    
}
```

I get "Cannot convert value of type 'Any?' to expected argument type 'String'" on

```
serverScalingString += "0," + json["srvFile0"] as? String + "|"
```

I don't need any null safety on the string `json["srvFile0"]`, if this would be null then the app can just crash

changing as? to as! doesn't work

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is ok to crash

```
let temp = json["srvFile0"]! as! String
```

But much better would be to avoid that

```
if let temp = json["srvFile0"], let serverFile = temp as? String {
```

Comment: Just tried: serverScalingString += "0," + json["srvFile0"]! as! String + "|" and still get: Cannot convert value of type 'Any' to expected argument type 'String'. But I'll take the second solution, thanks!